# Disable Keyboard Keys using Application.OnKey

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

Question1:
Having trouble disabling these keyboard keys using Application.Onkey, the keys are {  }  [  ]  Suggestions?

Comment: You might want to consider setting the file read-only instead and ask for an editing password: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-a-document-read-only-5c25909c-46d9-4eb0-9d1f-d072a560e340 **Any** attempt to add security with VBA can easily fail if people don't enable macros. Also note, that any Excel file can easily be replicated by creating a new empty Excel file and adding the formula `=[YourExcelFile.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` and then copying that formula over and across the newly created sheet.

Comment: Read this [Message for cross-posters](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184).

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the following to disable the keys`{}[]`

```
' Macro to turn off keyboard entry.

  Sub KeyboardOff() 
     Application.OnKey "{[}", ""
     Application.OnKey "+{{}", ""
     Application.OnKey "+{}}", ""
     Application.OnKey "{]}", ""
 End Sub
```

To Enable these entry add the following:

```
 ' Macro to turn on keyboard entry.
 Sub KeyboardOn() 
    Application.OnKey "{[}"
    Application.OnKey "+{{}"
    Application.OnKey "+{}}"
    Application.OnKey "{]}"
 End Sub
```